# How do I get my api-data to show up on my details list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can list all my products in my API through a view page by making a ProductsController like this:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var products = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Product>>("I won't write out my link so everyone can see it :P");

        return View(products);
```

after that I made a view page for the products like this.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p><small>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubCatergoryId)</small></p>
                <img src=" @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                <h5 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h5>
                <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center card-footer">
                    <p class="text-danger price pt-3">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price):-</p>
                    <a href="/home/details/@item.Id" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Details<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart me-2"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-box text-success my-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lagerstatus</i></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}
```

it worked perfect. But now I want to press the details button which takes me to another view (details page). This is the code for the details page:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">

        <div class="col-lg">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImageUrl)" class="card-img-top" alt="75\">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <b></b> <br>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</p>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <p class="text-danger price pt-3">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price):-</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                            Beställ
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart me-2"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-box text-success my-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lagerstatus</i></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I get: [Details Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1wto.png)

this is my first time working with Asp.net and making my own API.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Html.DisplayNameFor` shows the name of the property or the string defined in the display attribute for the property.

The `@Html.DisplayFor` shows the value of the field.

Change your code to:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">

        <div class="col-lg">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImageUrl)" class="card-img-top" alt="75\">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <b></b> <br>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
                    </p>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <p class="text-danger price pt-3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price):-</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                            Beställ
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart me-2"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-box text-success my-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Lagerstatus</i></small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Note:

Be sure the value of `model.ImageUrl` should equal to `/location/filename.extension`. Be sure **add single slash at the beginning** and specific the file name.